# How can I update component value in controller or route with ember?

Tags: ember.js

My `click-editable` component like:

Template:

```
{{#if isEdit}}
  <div class="input-group">
    {{input type="text" value=editValue class="form-control"}}
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn no-margin-btn btn-info" {{action "updateValue"}}>{{fa-icon 'check'}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{{else}}
  ....
{{/if}}
```

And:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "",
  isEdit: false,
  canEdit: true,
  category: 'input',
  editValue: Ember.computed.oneWay('value'),

  actions:{
    updateValue() {
      this.sendAction('onUpdate', this.get('valueModel'), this.get('valueColumn'), this.get('editValue'), this.get('isEdit'));
    }
  }
});
```

Use in my template:

```
{{#each model.quotationWorkItems as |quotationWorkItem index|}}
  {{click-editable valueModel=quotationWorkItem valueColumn='name' value=quotationWorkItem.name onUpdate=(action "updateInput")}}
{{/each}}
```

In the controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ....

  actions: {
    updateInput(updateModel, updateColumn, value, isEdit) {
      updateModel.set(updateColumn, value);
      updateModel.save().then(()=> {
        this.get('model').reload();
        this.set('isEdit', false);
      }, ()=> {
        alert('wrong');
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  ...

  model(params) {
    return this.store.find('quotation', params.quotation_id);
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    ...
  }
})
```

Quotation model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  quotationStocks: DS.hasMany('quotationStock'),
  quotationWorkItems: DS.hasMany('quotationWorkItem'),
  ...
});
```

QuotationWorkItem model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  transactionType: DS.belongsTo('transactionType'),
  quotation: DS.belongsTo('quotation'),

  ...
});
```

This code can update model value, but problem `isEdit` is the component value. When `isEdit` send to controller and set another value, it can not work. So I think can not change component value in ember controller?

```
this.set('isEdit', false);
```

The code can not work in controller. I'm using Ember 2.4.0.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the class of `model.quotationWorkItems`?

Comment: @Timm of course. But there is no contact with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the controller isEdit property to the component isEdit property.

```
{{click-editable isEdit=isEdit valueModel=quotationWorkItem valueColumn='name' value=quotationWorkItem.name onUpdate=(action "updateInput")}}
```

This will overwrite the `isEdit` property in the component (data down).

Comment: I edit my question. And I think if I use `isEdit = isEdit` I must add more component.